# TypeError: Data location must be "storage", "memory" or "calldata" for variable, but none was given

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan

I am trying to map an address to a struct object. While initializing the struct I get the following error:
TypeError: Data location must be "storage", "memory" or "calldata" for variable, but none was given.

Here is my code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: NONE
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
contract DropSite {
    uint public value = 123;
    
    struct NFT_Owner{
      string  name;
      uint nft_id;
    }
    mapping(address => NFT_Owner) public NFT_Ownership;
    address[] public NFT_Owners;

    function addValues( string memory _name, uint _nft_id) public {

      NFT_Owner owner = NFT_Owner({name:_name , nft_id: _nft_id}) ;
      
      NFT_Ownership[msg.sender] = owner;
      NFT_Owners.push(0xdD870fA1b7C4700F2BD7f44238821C26f7392148);
    }
     
  }
```

and the error is:
TypeError: Data location must be "storage", "memory" or "calldata" for variable, but none was given.
--> contracts/Transfer.sol:15:7:
|
15 | NFT_Owner owner = NFT_Owner({name:_name , nft_id: _nft_id}) ;

Anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  NFT_Owner owner = NFT_Owner({name:_name , nft_id: _nft_id}) ;
```

Since Solidity 0.5.x

> Explicit data location for all variables of struct, array, or mapping
> types is now mandatory.

```
NFT_Owner memory owner = NFT_Owner({name:_name, nft_id: _nft_id});
```

You need to add `memory` keyword